# How to unlock fields with java script function in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to add java script function to CRM 2011 account
that open disable field for editing.

I wrote:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(“fieldname”).setDisabled(false);
```

but it doesn't work, and keep asking me a function.
How should I write it?

Comment: what type of control is `fieldname`? The code that you have should work

Comment: What is triggering the JavaScript? Are you sure the code is even getting called? Are you using the logical name of the field? The display name will not work; also look at the debug window in the browser (press F12), are there any errors?

Comment: What is the value of `Xrm.Page.getControl("fieldname")`?

Answer (score 3):

I use the following:

```
var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("fieldname");

if (control != null)
{
    control.setDisabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to add javascript to account entity:

1. open crm 2011. Click on settings
2. Click on customizations
3. Click on customize the system
4. Click on entities
5. click on account entity open the tree view
6. click on forms
7. click on information form type = main
8. click on form properties
9. click on add -> new -> enter name of web resource
10. select type jscript
11. In the text editor enter the following code:

    ```
    function Unlock()
    {
    var control = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("fieldname");

    if (control != null)
     {
    control.setDisabled(false);
     }
     }
    ```

Save and close. Publish the function.
 then in event Handlers click add 
  Select the recently added library and enter function name Unlock   without braces

```
   Save and Publish
```

Comment: thank you.i didn't it but i get the excepion: the value of the property 'unlock' is null or undefined, not a function object. what is wrong?

Comment: Do not mention the ()  with function while adding to the event handler

Comment: Add the function like Unlock    in the function name text box

Comment: Ok i got it.... you have a missing bracket in your code.
Please build the js file in VS and check in warnings you may have an error regarding syntax.

Comment: @user2421945 If you find my answer correct. Please mark it as correct.